# vba : do something only on the first for each loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
for each element in sarray
  if ... then
     if this is the first time the above IF statenent was executed ... then
  end if
next element
```

i want to do something ONLY the first time that the first `IF THEN` statement is executed. i am having a lot of problems with my logic. please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var isExecuted = false
for each element in sarray
  if ... then
     if Not isExecuted Then
        --do stuff
       isExecuted = true
     end if
  end if
next element
```

Comment: If that's all the loop has to do, then add 'Exit For' as the last line of the do stuff routine.

Answer (score 2):

```
flag = true
For each ...
   if flag 
       do whatever with first element
       flag = false
   endif
   do what you want with all elements ... including the first
next
```

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way of doing this but you can have a boolean variable first_time which will start out as true and get set to false in the if statement. You can then check

```
If first_time = True Then
   Stuff
End If
```

Comment: @belisarius: In fact, this is the only piece of VBA code so far in this question. Your will not compile. Nor will @CDeutsch's.

Comment: @GSerg **and get set to false in the if statement** .. in VBA?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you have N elements, and you want to perform some operation only for the first element. So doing this like you want to do is waste of processor time.

So I would suggest to rewrite your logic without introducing a new boolean variable. It's cleaner and faster. Something like this for example:

```
Dim intCount As Integer    

If (some condition) Then
  DoSomething with sarray(0)
For intCount = 1 To sarray.Length
     //Do something
Next intCount
```

Comment: It's not the first object of the array, it's the first one that satisfies the condition. What if sarray(5) is the first one for which the If condition is True?

Comment: You assume that it is the first element that satisfies the condition, but to be honest anything can be put between if ... then, and since user did not say what condition is really there i think my answer stays valid.